# How to force a Django model to reload fields after saving without using refresh_from_db?

Tags: python, django, orm, model

I have the following Django models:
Device had a foreign key to Deployment
I have the adopt method in Device that set the deployment for a device and perform some additional logic.

notice that I pass an id and not a Deployment instance to the adopt method

```py
class Device(Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True)
    deployment = models.ForeignKey(
        Deployment, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True, related_name='devices'
    )

    def adopt(self, deployment_id):
        self.deployment_id = deployment_id
        self.full_clean()

        with transaction.atomic():
            self.save()

            # self.refresh_from_db()

            if self.deployment.private: # this might fail.. see examples
                # additional logic
                pass


class Deployment(TimeStampedModel, DeploymentResource):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    private = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

If I do not access to the deployment field of the Device instance, adopt() works as expected.
example:

```py
device = Device.objects.get(pk=device_id)
device.adopt(deployment_id) # this works
```

if instead I load the deployment field before calling adopt, when I call Adopt I get an `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'private'`

this does not works:

```py
device = Device.objects.get(pk=device_id)
print(device.deployment) # example of accessing/loading the field/relation
device.adopt(deployment_id) # this will generate the attribute error
```

The cause is pretty obvious. device.deployment was None, its value has been loaded and stored inside the model but it's not automatically reloaded and substituted with the new deployment after the save() call.
The first example works simply because the deployment relation has never been accessed before the save.

An obvious solution is to call refresh_from_db after saving (see comment inside adopt method) but this will generate an additional query that I would like to avoid.
Is there a way to force the model to forget the "cached" value of the deployment attribute that does not involve an additional query?

edit: clarified where the exception is raised

Answer (score 0):

I´m not sure if i understand this correctly but to me it seems like the problem is rather that the default value of deployment is null.
So if you try to access deployment without assigning a deployment object first it will be null.

Please check if you are assigning deployment before calling device.deployment and if so please provide some code so i can recreate your situation.

Comment: If you look at the first line of adopt method I'm assigning the deployment_id which is enough to create the relation. but the inconvenient is that it leave the deployment as None. 
This is not an issue if you didn't load the deployment field before.

An option would be to pass a Deployment instance instead of deployment_id to the adopt method but it's something I would like to avoid.

Comment: Thats not what i meant. If i understand your code correctly you only assign the deployment to your device with adopt(). But you are trying to access device.deployment before assigning it with adopt() so it will be None.
Are you still facing this issue when calling print(device.deployment) after adopt?

Comment: Correct I assign a deployment to a device using the adopt method.
The part were I've probably not been clear is that the attribute error is generated by the line:
`if self.deployment.private:` inside the adopt method. so there is no "after adopt"

the print(device.deployment) is just an example of "loading" the value of deployment.
a more meaningful example could be the following:
`
device = Device.objects.get(pk=device_id)
if device.deployment is None:
    device.adopt(deployment_id)
else:
    logger.warning('device already adopted')
`

Comment: my problem is that adopt fails if I access the deployment before calling adopt because its value is loaded and kept in memory.
I would like to find a way to invalidate this "cached" value so that it's reloaded after the save with the new real relation.

Comment: Ah i think i get it now.
I´ll recreate it once i get home because i´m pretty sure i´ve never had this issue.